# How should I connect a new light fixture to three black wires and one red?

Tags: electrical

I'm changing my light fitting and I have 3 black wires, 1 white. I have tried combinations and cant get the upstairs light to come back on. Can someone help?

[image]

Comment: Location would be helpful because of different wiring techniques in different countries.

Comment: If you have the slack available I suggest cleaning up those ends. Cut them back and carefully re-strip.

Comment: How were they connected to the old fitting?

Comment: In from the UK, Wales.

Comment: And I dont know how they were wired i forgot to take a picture 

Comment: Can you discern how the wires are paired up into cables? If you hook the lamp to the black and red that are in the same cable, does it light continuously and ignore the switch?